# Mouse Motion Listener

Tags: java, arrays, awt

I am a beginner at Java programming. I am trying to create a checkers game in which players can move their own pieces. The problem is that when one piece is moved, all of them move it. I would really appreciate some help. Thanks!!!

Main Class

```
package Checkers_Own;

import resources.DrawingBoard;
import resources.Timer;

public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Board[][] boards = new Board[8][8];
        DrawingBoard board = new DrawingBoard(840, 640);
        Timer timer = new Timer();

        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++){
                if(i % 2 == 1){
                    if(j % 2 == 1)boards[i][j] = new Board(true, i, j);
                    else boards[i][j] = new Board(false, i, j);
                }
                else if(i % 2 == 0){
                    if(j % 2 == 1)boards[i][j] = new Board(false, i, j);
                    else boards[i][j] = new Board(true, i, j);
                }
            }
        }
        for(int i = 5; i < 8; i++) for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++) if(!boards[j][i].isWhite) PiecesManager.add1(new Pieces(true, j, i));
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) if(!boards[i][j].isWhite) PiecesManager.add2(new Pieces(false, i, j));

        PiecesManager.properties(board);

        while(true){
            board.clear();
            for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++) boards[i][j].draw(board);
            PiecesManager.draw(board);
            PiecesManager.move();
            board.repaint();
            timer.pause(30);
        }
    }
}
```

Pieces

```
package Checkers;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import resources.DrawingBoard;

public class Pieces implements MouseMotionListener, MouseListener{

    boolean side1, changed = false;
    int x, y, lastX, lastY, dx, dy;

    public Pieces(boolean side1, int x, int y){
        this.side1 = side1;
        this.x = (x * 80) + 10;
        this.y = (y * 80) + 10;
    }

    public void draw(DrawingBoard board){
        Graphics2D g = board.getCanvas();
        if(side1){
            g.setColor(Color.blue);
            g.fillOval(x, y, 60, 60);
        }
        else{
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillOval(x, y, 60, 60);
        }
    }

    public Pieces moved(){
        if(changed){
            return this;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void move(){
        if(changed){
            x += dx;
            y += dy;
        }
        changed = false;
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {    
        lastX = e.getX();
        lastY = e.getY();
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {    
        int mx = e.getX();
        dx = mx - lastX;
        lastX = mx;
        int my = e.getY();
        dy = my - lastY;
        lastY = my;
        if(mx != x || my != y) changed = true;
    }
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
}
```

Board

```
 package Checkers_Own;

    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;
    import resources.DrawingBoard;

    public class Board {

        boolean isWhite;
        private int x, y;

        public Board(boolean isWhite, int x, int y){
            this.isWhite = isWhite;
            this.x = x * 80;
            this.y = y * 80;
        }

        public void draw(DrawingBoard board){
            Graphics2D g = board.getCanvas();
            if(isWhite){
                g.setColor(Color.white);
                g.fillRect(x, y, 80, 80);
            }
            else{
                g.setColor(Color.black);
                g.fillRect(x, y, 80, 80);
            }
        }
    }
```

PiecesManager

```
package Checkers_Own;

import resources.DrawingBoard;

public class PiecesManager {

private static int size1, size2;
private static Pieces[] p1 = new Pieces[12];
private static Pieces[] p2 = new Pieces[12];

public static void draw(DrawingBoard board){
    for(int i = 0; i < size1; i++) p1[i].draw(board);   
    for(int i = 0; i < size2; i++) p2[i].draw(board);   
}

public static void move(){
    for(int i = 0; i < p1.length; i++) if(p1[i].moved() == p1[i]) p1[i].move();
    for(int i = 0; i < p2.length; i++) if(p2[i].moved() == p2[i]) p2[i].move();
}

public static void add1(Pieces piece){
    p1[size1] = piece;
    size1 ++;
}

public static void add2(Pieces piece){
    p2[size2] = piece;
    size2 ++;
}

public static void properties(DrawingBoard board){
    for(int i = 0; i < p1.length; i++){
        board.addMouseListener(p1[i]);
        board.addMouseMotionListener(p1[i]);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < p2.length; i++){
        board.addMouseListener(p2[i]);
        board.addMouseMotionListener(p2[i]);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You have a copy and paste error.  Your PieceManager class is same as game class

Comment: so sorry will fix

Comment: That `while (true)` loop has no place in this event-driven GUI. It looks like you're trying to shoe-horn linear console code into an event driven GUI, and this is definitely something that you do **not** want to do.

Comment: i don't know what you mean

Comment: Just what I said.

Comment: Add your drawingBoard class too, if you could.

Comment: It's just his way of building the game engine.  He will learn more about how to make the engine, don't worry.

Comment: I'd start by having a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/).  Swing uses a passive rendering algorithm, for what you're doing, it's more the enough. Don't use `getGraphics`, this really isn't how painitng should be done in this context